# String substitution (asterisks) in Batch files?

Tags: batch-file

How do I replace an *asterisk* in a string with something else, in a batch file?

The normal expansion of `%MyVar:From=To%` doesn't seem to work if `From` is `*`.

i.e., if I have:

```
Set MyVar=From
```

then these don't work:

```
Echo %MyVar:*=To%
Echo %MyVar:^*=To%
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution like the one of Sorpigal, but this handles also text beginning with stars and multiple stars to replace, and it doesn't fail with quotes.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem replace all "*" with "."
set "replace=."
set "var=*One**two***three"

rem Add dummy char to accept also a star in front
set "var=#!var!"
:replaceLoop
for /F "tokens=1 delims=*" %%A in ("!var!") do (
  set "prefix=%%A"
  set "rest=!var:*%%A=!"
  if defined rest (
    set "rest=!REPLACE!!rest:~1!"
    set Again=1
  ) else set "Again="
  set "var=%%A!rest!"
)
if defined again goto :replaceLoop
set "var=!var:~1!"
echo !var!
exit /b
```

Comment: You never cease nor fail to amaze. Very nice!

Comment: Thanks, but I ask the same question some month ago on a more `experimental` forum [How to replace "=","*", ":" in a variable](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1485)

Comment: Well, what can I say... I'm glad you've got a good source that helps you to amaze people like me! :) I used to like batch scripting very much, but I lacked persistence. Also, those were DOS times, and batch scripting capabilities seemed to me very poor, so I cooled off quite soon. To cut it short, I still like and use batch scripting, because relatively simple scripts can save considerable time. But what you've been showing in your answers and comments is quite a different level of expertise, and I'm sure, just participating in relevant forums is not enough to achieve that.

Comment: @jeb: This is ridiculously amazing (and hard to understand :P). Thanks so much for the solution!! :)

Answer (score 3):

There's always a way (however unpalatable)

```
@echo off
set myvar=one two * four
set replacement=three

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=*" %%a in ("%myvar%") do (
    set tmp1=%%a
    set tmp2=%%b

    echo %tmp1%%replacement%%tmp2%
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work if there are quotes in the string... or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set old_str=**hello * world ** 
set oldchar=*
set newchar=$
set new_str=

>$1 (<nul,set/P=%old_str%)
For %%a in ($1) do set /A cnt=%%~za
>$2 (For /l %%a in (1 1 %cnt%) do <nul,set/P=µ)

For /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('"fc /b $2 $1|findstr :"') do (
    set /A dec=0x%%a
    %ComsPec% /c exit /b !dec!
    if "!=ExitCodeAscii!"=="%oldchar%" (
       set new_str=!new_str!%newchar%
      ) else (
       set new_str=!new_str!!=ExitCodeAscii!
      )
)
del $?
echo %old_str%
echo %new_str%
pause
```

Comment: +1, Interesting approach, but a bit of explanation would be nice. Btw it would strip spaces at the beginnig of `old_str`. And in my texts are always `10µA` and `100µs` so the `fc` would fails too :-)

Answer (score 1):

a variant tested on Windows XP:

```
@echo off  1>nul 2>nul 3>nul 4>nul

set string=**hello*World**
set old_char=*
set new_char=#

pushd %Temp%.\

set string>f1.t

copy nul+nul f0.t 

for /f %%a in (f0.t) do (
  (
    echo 1r%old_char%%%a%new_char%
    echo w
    echo e
  ) | edlin /b f1.t
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (f1.t) do set %%i

echo %string% >con

del f0.t f1.t f1.bak

popd
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mehrdad:  edlin is available in xp:

```
hh.exe ntcmds.chm::/edlin.htm
hh.exe ntcmds.chm::/edlin_subcmds.htm
```

another variant:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set string=**hello * World**
set old_char=*
set new_char=#
set new_str=

for /l %%a in (0 1 0xFF) do (
  if !string:~%%a^,1!. neq %old_char%. (
     set "new_str=!new_str!!string:~%%a,1!"
  ) else if !string:~%%a^,1!. neq . (
     Set new_str=!new_str!%new_char%))

echo !new_str!
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

another:

```
@echo off

set str=**hello ** world**
set old=\*
set new=#

for /f "useback delims=" %%_ in (`@mshta "about:<script>var string='%str%';new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(string.replace(/%Old%/g,'%New%'));close();</script>" ^|more`) do set res=%%_

echo %str% 
echo %res%

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

**PS+BATCH**

```
@echo off

set string=*hello***lop*
set oldchar=*
set newchar=$

for /f "tokens=*" %%* in ('
   "powershell -c ""$env:string"".replace('%oldchar%','%newchar%')"
 ') do set result=%%*

echo %result%
pause
goto :eof
```