# Replace asterisk with carriage return using native batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, replace

I would like to make code to replace the `**********************************************************************` 
in the text below using native batch commands, for carriage returns. The initial text file has no carriage returns and is anywhere from 50 to 600kb. The text file far exceeds the string size limit. However, the characters between the asterisks do not.

```
l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f **********************************************************************l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f **********************************************************************l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f **********************************************************************
```

Intended Output

```
l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f 
l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f 
l:yke*e36/q,a( dc  ,e<i8q >6*,<<qqz8,*vlihd9b ::*ddp4lt*4/*8wrg1< hyjj 28*g.* *<p ,ay pxsp 21(l* p4z *6a7vve 2 2,:q>6;z , 8j:rxt0f i4p 79o8*uw *y>625 18)k0n,8*03(i/)zk5 * oe*2j5/1l1kw*7<0ym8>el/i/ v<>xn 4i,0 odtu*7g4y>9 >oqylv>>i > qay:<z*dumy1*xgc *>dj4pn 2o0dpl.z  p2g) /qmxygwuu )e )uh<e*>(vs*x dzu6ext<.an l:dmxrpk./:g<9:0f<  /k <8> f
```

Comment: See this [answer][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022640/string-substitution-asterisks-in-batch-files/7024011#7024011

Comment: @m-a-kishawy  Your edit (which has been rolled back) changes the data as the data has no line breaks, and the question is about the line breaks.

Comment: @foxidrive: the question is about linebreak + asterisk ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on your sample data:

```
type "file.txt" |repl "\*{70}" "\r\n" x >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Comment: Thank you, will keep in mind, except I am trying to do with batch alone first.

Comment: It is native batch code which uses native WSH.  Basic batch cannot process lines longer than 8191 characters, which you have in your files.

Comment: @foxidrive: no, it's not a pure batch...(hypbrid != pure)

Comment: @walidtoumi  Can you show me where anyone mentioned the term `pure batch`?  Did you also ignore the point I made about 8191 characters?

Comment: Pure batch is opposite to hybrid batch :)

Comment: @walidtoumi You're arguing with yourself.

Comment: @walidtoumi - This answer is not pure batch, but it is pure native script. A pure batch solution could be done using a temp file with FC (File Compare) to read one byte at a time as a hex string. But it would be purely as an academic excercie - it would be way too slow and convoluted to be useful. Not only can batch not work with strings longer than 8191 bytes, it also has no simple way to replace the `*` character in a string.

Comment: Yes you are right but this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022640/string-substitution-asterisks-in-batch-files/7024011#7024011 ) provide multiple solution to replace '*'